# Inherit ownership and permissions to directories and files

Tags: debian, setgid, sticky-bit

I have a directory `test` with the owner user:group and 770 as permissions.

I want, that every directory and file within `test` do have the same specifications.

I tried `chmod g+s,u+s test`, which partially worked: directories within that folder do inherit the ownership and permissions, but files only the owners, not the permissions.
I also tried `chmod g+t test`, which was a total failure.

How can i achieve the desired result?

Edit: the administrator does not allow to install ACL and umask does dont work, since the files won't be generates from a CLI

Comment: You want all files to be executable?

Answer (score 0):

the `setgid` (+s) : have sometimes different meaning amongst different unix OSes.
However they enable user and group inheritance, but not permissions inheritance.

Permissions are by default set using the "umask" of each user.

If the umask was "0", the files and directories would be created with the rights: rwxrwxrws by default (ie, octal mode 777, or binary: 111111111), and thus would be : readable, writable, and executable (or, for directories: "crossing-able") for the owner (the first rwx triplet), the group the file is associated to (the 2nd rwx triplet) and for everyone/everything else (the 3rd "rwx" triplet).

The umask: can "mask" some of those bits.

Usually root's umask is more retrictive, for exemple: 077 (meaning it will hide all the group & other bits, as "077" octal is : 000111111 in binary) and a regular user is usually 022 (ie, 000010010) meaning it will "hide" (remove) just the "write" bit for both the group and the "others triplets) .

ie:

```
without umask the file or directory have those triplets:
rwx rwx rwx , ie:  111 111 111
If created by root, with a umask of : 077, this file would instead have:     
    111 111 111
XOR 000 111 111
  = 111 000 000, thus : rwx --- --- (ie, only the owner can read/write/execute it)
If created by a user, with a umask of : 022, it would instead have:
    111 111 111
XOR 000 010 010
  = 111 101 101, thus : rwx r-x r-x
```

Comment: I changed `sticky bit` to `setgid` as the latter is what you are describing. The `sticky bit` is denoted by `t` and is applied to directories like `/tmp` which is world writable to set it so that users can only modify data that they own.

Comment: @NasirRiley : many thanks, I indeed should have checked the proper terms ^^ (I used them a lot more ... 20 years ago than now)